# How to check flag value with only ints and standard math

Tags: c#, sharepoint, flags, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity

I want to check flag value when I have only ints values:

[image]

So when I have `int x = 54` it means that it is **0110110**, BUT i am doing sharepoint declarative custom actions without possibility to create flag code etc. I can only do simple expressions with no use of enums.

So now I get a day `int monday = 32`,

so my question is:

How I can check that 54 has flag 32, it can be mathematic way or some simple algoritm with simple loop

**UPDATE:**

referenced to Andrew Whitaker

[image]

goes with error

> Failed to translate expression '(workDaysValueInt & 32 )==32' because
>   of the following error: Logical operations allow only boolean data
>   types.

`

funny thing is that when I use raw data for example (54 & 32) == 32 it has no errors at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use bitwise `&` and compare the result with the day of the week you're checking for:

```
int Monday = 32;
int days = 54;

bool hasMonday = (days & Monday) == Monday;
```

Here's what this looks like:

```
  110110
& 100000
  -------
  100000
```

The reason this works is when you're using integer values as flags (and combining the flags using bitwise `|`), the result of an `&` operation with a flag value will yield what you're `&`ing with if it contains that flag, in a sense stripping out the other information contained in the value.

Comment: your answere is absolutly right... but, what is strange when I use variables i got error "Failed to translate expression '(workDaysValueInt & 32 )==32' because of the following error:
Logical operations allow only boolean data types."

Comment: That might be a sharepoint issue... I'm afraid I don't know much about sharepoint

Comment: i update question according to your answere witch is in some way is good